# Asp.net View States in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, viewstate

I am asp.net developer, currently switched to django. I am working on first app and have to maintain user data for some time and then send it to db unless user save button is clicked.

I want to know if django provides some kinds of alternatives to view states  to store data temp within a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain what "view states" are, but I guess you are looking for [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/).

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear what you are actually looking for, because viewstates is just a way to preserve data.

1. If you need to store information for a particular user, but not commit it to a database, use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/) as Daniel suggested.
2. If you are create a multi-step form (also called a "wizard"), and need to preserve state between each step/form; use [Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).